# Authentication useing PHP SDK not working

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am having some trouble with authentication using PHP SDK. I have downloaded "facebook.php" and "base_facebook.php" from github. 
Below is the code I am useing but cant figure out where I am going wrong (new to all this).

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php' ;
$fbconfig['appid' ] = xxx;
$fbconfig['secret'] = "xxxx";
$fbconfig['baseurl'] = "xxx";
$params = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
'redirect_uri' => 'xxx'
);
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params​);
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  if(!$user)
     {
        echo "<P>You need to <a href=\"' . $loginUrl . '\">log into FB</a></p>\n";
        exit();
     }
  else
     {
         echo "<p style=\"margin-bottom:20px;\">​<a href=\"{$logoutUrl}\">Logout</​p>\n";
      }
 ?>
```

Any suggestions much appriciated :)

Comment: What is the behavior you expect, and what is the script actually doing?

Comment: I want it to simply display a "log into FB" link if the user is not loged in and a "Logout" button if they are. When I run the code I get the following PHP error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object in /xx/xx/xx/xx.php on line 20"

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), it looks like you need to explicitly construct your own `Facebook` object:

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config[‘secret’] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

Comment: The behavior has changed, now even if I am loged in to FB the page reads "You need to log in with FB" and when I click it it takes me to facebook.com and reads "An error occurred. Please try later"

Comment: Given that $user is undefined, of course it will always prompt for login. The error sounds like something is wrong in $config - you should probably check the documentation.

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that $user came from facebook.php. I will continue try and decipher the documentation.

Comment: I cant find anything in the documentation that helps :(